# No data selected for export after I used a "WHERE" clause to filter data on mutiple tables and query in MS access using SQL in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, where-clause

I can got the data normaly from SELECT without the WHERE clause but after I added "WHERE" clause, no data selected for export. I just want to make one quotation at a time by the input quotation no.

Here's the code:

```
SQL = "SELECT Customers.Company, Customers.Person, Customers.Telefone, Customers.[E-Mail], " & _
"Customers.Address, Customers.City, Customers.Postcode, Customers.Province, Customers.[USCI Num], " & _
"Customers.[Short Name], [Quotation Query1].Buyer, [Quotation Query1].[Quotation No], " & _
"[Quotation Query1].[Quotation Date], [Quotation Query1].Revision, " & _
"[Quotation Query1].Article_No, [Quotation Query1].Quantity, [Quotation Query1].Matchcode, " & _
"[Quotation Query1].RMB_price,[Quotation Query1].[Our Reference], Spare_Parts.Description, Spare_Parts.[Weight (kg)] " & _
"FROM Spare_Parts INNER JOIN (Customers INNER JOIN [Quotation Query1] ON Customers.[Short Name] = [Quotation Query1].[Buyer]) ON Spare_Parts.[Article_No] = [Quotation Query1].[Article_No] " & _
"WHERE Str([Quotation Query1].[Quotation No]) = 'MyValue' "
'To select only one quotation with the quotation no. to make the quotation
'It's bug free now but rsl.RecordCount goes to 0
```

Comment: `....)='" & strValue & "')"` where strValue is the value of your input

Comment: Thx but still no data selected for export.

Comment: Any rows selected when dropping the WHERE clause? And what is MyValue? Be specific.

Comment: Is the field `Quotation No` numeric or why are you converting it to a string? In that case, you should do it vice versa, convert `MyValue` to a number (and remove the single quotes).

Comment: If there's no WHERE clase, data of all quotations are selected instead of one. MyValue is an input string from "MyValue = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)".The "Quotation No" is an auto number. I tried  "WHERE [Quotation Query1].[Quotation No] = CInt(MyValue)  " but got "Error Number:3601 = Too few parameters. Expected 1."